# Bug in PowerShell Invoke-sqlcmd - Inserting duplicate rows if the second row of SQL insert statement table name is wrong

Tags: powershell

**Example:**

```
create table TestDB..TestTable
(
    Id Int,
    InsertedDate Datetime default (getdate()))
```

**Run below script in PowerShell, which has table name wrong in second row.**

```
$Query = "Use TestDB

Insert into TestTable (id) values ('1')

Insert into TestTable2 (id) values ('2')"

Invoke-sqlcmd -Query "$Query" -ServerInstance "SQLInstanceName"
```

**SQLResult:**

```
Id  InsertedDate

1   2016-09-15 03:35:12.587

1   2016-09-15 03:35:12.590
```

But it should insert only one row in a table, where as it inserted two rows.

Comment: 2 `INSERT`s = 2 rows. It works as expected.

Comment: What is the question?  StackOverflow is a question and answer forum, not a software defect reporting platform.  Also, maybe you need to separate the two INSERT commands with a semicolon.

Comment: Hi Tony,
FYI.
Even if you add semicolon, It is inserting duplicate rows.

$Query = "Use EZ_Automation

Insert into TestTable (id) values ('1');

Insert into TestTable2 (id) values ('2');"  

Could you please check it.